# Object is not rendered

Tags: rendering

I have tried everything, but the object, the large cylinder at the center, just won't render. This happened after I applied smoothness and some modifiers, like edge modifier and subdivision surface. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Blender file is provided:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GHBVLRvRttWnhZOHlZVTdNRGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't find how to fix this... where does it come fomr? it has some references to an SVG file...

Comment: I imported the green squares from SVG, it is coin's outer circle, some sort of physical texture. the SVG is no longer needed after the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Duplication enabled on the cylinder.  Please see [the manual for proper Dupligroup use](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html):

[image]

**EDIT:** Without knowing the history behind the creation of this blend, it's hard to say why that was like that and what/how it was being duplicated.  You and @m.ardito mentioned linking from an external file.  As the manual states:

> Note that if the DupliGroup was linked from an external file the Object Data (mesh, materials, textures, transforms) will also still be linked from the original group. However, the various object’s parent-child relationships do not carry over.

Comment: wow! that's right, but how did you find this out ?

Comment: Hello @Nulik , please see edit above

Comment: the cylinder object wasn't imported, only the squares. I must have been clicked on "Group" somehow, and since I don't know that it has hiding functionality I had troubles to find out what happened. I don't know yet how to link from external file , I'm just a beginner.

Comment: @Nulik - Yes, if you never used duplication in you project, then it was probably just an accident.  It *is* interesting that Blender will display the object in all cases but Rendered Mode.